# I need to loop through a table using criteria from a sub query of that same table

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a table of election results by precinct. I need to report the vote results for a specific proposition in each State Representative District.

(1) I have to figure out what State Representative Districts there are.
(2) I have to figure out which precincts are in each of the 163 State Representative Districts.
(3) I have to sum the results of votes for a specific proposition in all the precincts that make up each of the State Representative Districts.

Results should look something like this: `State Representative - District 1 Proposition B   6162    6397`

I know how to do all the pieces, but not how to put them into one query.

**List the State Representative Districts:**

```
SELECT distinct Office_Title FROM cmr.cmr2
where Office_Title LIKE 'State Representative - District%'
```

**List precincts for a particular State House District:**

```
SELECT distinct CONCAT(County_Name, '-', Precinct_Name) FROM cmr.cmr2 
where
Office_Title LIKE 'State Representative - District 1'
```

**Sum the vote totals on a given Proposition for one State Representative District:**

```
SELECT Office_Title, 
SUM(Yes_votes) as Yes_Total, 
SUM(No_votes) as NO_Total 
FROM cmr.cmr2 AS CMRA

where
CMRA.Office_Title LIKE 'Proposition B'
and
CONCAT(County_Name, '-', Precinct_Name) in
(
SELECT distinct CONCAT(County_Name, '-', Precinct_Name) FROM cmr.cmr2 AS CMRB
where
CMRB.Office_Title LIKE 'State Representative - District 10'
)
```

I need to loop through the results from the first query (the list of State Representative Districts) where I have 'State Representative - District 10' in the last line of code, above.

Thanks, in advance for your help!

Here is some sample data:

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| idcmr2 | County_Name | Precinct_Code | Precinct_Name | Office_Title                      | Candidate_Ballot_Name | Political_Party | Yes_votes | No_votes | Election      | Special_1 | Special_2 |
+--------+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
|    181 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHWEST 1   | State Representative - District 3 | Danny Busick          | NULL            |       258 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    182 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 2   | State Representative - District 3 | Danny Busick          | NULL            |       620 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    183 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 3   | State Representative - District 1 | Danny Busick          | NULL            |       187 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    184 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 4   | State Representative - District 1 | Danny Busick          | NULL            |       306 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    193 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHWEST 1   | State Representative - District 2 | Joni Perry            | NULL            |       248 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    194 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 2   | State Representative - District 2 | Joni Perry            | NULL            |       474 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    195 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 3   | State Representative - District 3 | Joni Perry            | NULL            |       340 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    196 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 4   | State Representative - District 3 | Joni Perry            | NULL            |       415 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    205 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHWEST 1   | State Representative - District 4 | Greg Sharpe           | NULL            |         0 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    206 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 2   | State Representative - District 4 | Greg Sharpe           | NULL            |         0 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    207 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 3   | State Representative - District 4 | Greg Sharpe           | NULL            |         0 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    208 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 4   | State Representative - District 4 | Greg Sharpe           | NULL            |         0 |     NULL | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    277 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHWEST 1   | Proposition B                     |                       | NULL            |       327 |      170 | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    278 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 2   | Proposition B                     |                       | NULL            |       594 |      485 | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    279 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 3   | Proposition B                     |                       | NULL            |       362 |      163 | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    280 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 4   | Proposition B                     |                       | NULL            |       493 |      234 | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    289 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHWEST 1   | Proposition C                     |                       | NULL            |       226 |      270 | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    290 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 2   | Proposition C                     |                       | NULL            |       403 |      680 | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    291 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 3   | Proposition C                     |                       | NULL            |       239 |      286 | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
|    292 | Adair       | NULL          | SOUTHEAST 4   | Proposition C                     |                       | NULL            |       300 |      415 | November 2018 | NULL      | NULL      |
+--------+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Here is what I want the output to look like:

```
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
| District                          | Ballot Measure        | Yes_votes | No_votes | Election      |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
| State Representative - District 1 | Proposition B         | 7634      |     8745 | November 2018 |
| State Representative - District 2 | Proposition B         | 7435      |      876 | November 2018 |
| State Representative - District 3 | Proposition B         | 9876      |     9831 | November 2018 |
| State Representative - District 4 | Proposition B         | 3453      |     2343 | November 2018 |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
```

I tried using the individual queries I listed above.  They produce the results I want, individually, but I can't figure out how to make it into one query and loop through the State Representative Districts automatically.

Comment: Please add representative sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: P.Salmon, I added sample data and output.  (Vote totals are not actual) THANKS!

Comment: Given there are no State Representative - District 1 or State Representative - District 2 in the sample the sample cannot be representative..

Comment: See if the changes to the data I made help.

Answer (score 0):

While "looping" might help you think through what's needed from a procedural context, it's the wrong way to think about relational data and sql, which is a set based language. You want to think in sets of data and how they join (or how they relate) to each-other.

In this case you want to join to a subquery that has your distinct districts on the relationship between `County_Name` and `District_Name`:

```
SELECT t2.District, 
  t1.Office_Title as Ballot_Measure,
  SUM(t1.Yes_votes) as Yes_Total, 
  SUM(t1.No_votes) as NO_Total, 
  t1.Election
FROM
  CMR.CMR2 t1
  INNER JOIN 
     (
         SELECT DISTINCT County_Name, District_Name, Office_Title as District
         FROM CMR.CMR2 
         WHERE candidate_ballot_name IS NOT NULL --just trying to narrow in on the type of record we are interested in for this subquery
     ) t2 
     ON t1.County_Name = t2.County_Name 
         AND t1.District_Name = t2.District_Name
WHERE t1.Office_Title = 'Proposition B'
GROUP BY District, Ballot_Measure, Election
```